# How to install gPXE/Etherboot to the hard drive?

Tags: pxe-boot

I have a remote system on rescue mode where i need to start gPXE. I cannot connect an USB stick to the system and so on.

Is there any way i can install [gPXE](http://etherboot.org/wiki/index.php) to the hard drive so that once rebooted it will be started instead of the OS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have some idea about PXE boot or network boot.

In most cases, you don't need to install gPXE in your hard drive. All you need is enable PXE/Network boot in your bios and make it the 1st booting device.

Following are some links related to PXE boot

https://superuser.com/a/521077/170017 <- This is a guild line for setting up Windows net boot, but should be easily adopted for Linux too.

http://etherboot.org/wiki/howtos <- A lot of information about how to setup gPXE

Comment: Does this help or you still have issue with pxe boot?